# How to repeat tensor in a specific new dimension in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, repeat

If I have a tensor `A` which has shape `[M, N]`,
I want to repeat the tensor K times so that the result `B` has shape `[M, K, N]`
and each slice `B[:, k, :]` should has the same data as `A`.
Which is the best practice without a for loop.
`K` might be in other dimension.

`torch.repeat_interleave()` and `tensor.repeat()` does not seem to work. Or I am using it in a wrong way.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

[`tensor.repeat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.repeat.html?highlight=tensor%20repeat#torch.Tensor.repeat) should suit your needs but you need to insert a unitary dimension first. For this we could use either [`tensor.unsqueeze`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.unsqueeze.html?highlight=tensor%20unsqueeze#torch.Tensor.unsqueeze)  or [`tensor.reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.reshape.html?highlight=tensor%20reshape#torch.Tensor.reshape). Since `unsqueeze` is specifically defined to insert a unitary dimension we will use that.

```
B = A.unsqueeze(1).repeat(1, K, 1)
```

*Code Description* `A.unsqueeze(1)` turns `A` from an `[M, N]` to `[M, 1, N]` and `.repeat(1, K, 1)` repeats the tensor `K` times along the second dimension.

Answer (score 11):

[Einops](https://github.com/arogozhnikov/einops) provides repeat function

```py
import einops
einops.repeat(x, 'm n -> m k n', k=K)
```

`repeat` can add arbitrary number of axes in any order and reshuffle existing axes at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

`tensor.expand` might be a better choice than `tensor.repeat` because  according to [this](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.expand.html#torch.Tensor.expand): "*Expanding a tensor does not allocate new memory, but only creates a new view on the existing tensor where a dimension of size one is expanded to a larger size by setting the stride to 0.*"

However, be aware that: "*More than one element of an expanded tensor may refer to a single memory location. As a result, in-place operations (especially ones that are vectorized) may result in incorrect behavior. If you need to write to the tensors, please clone them first.*"

```
M = N = K = 3
A = torch.arange(0, M * N).reshape((M, N))
B = A.unsqueeze(1).expand(M, K, N)
B

'''
tensor([[[0, 1, 2],
         [0, 1, 2],
         [0, 1, 2]],

        [[3, 4, 5],
         [3, 4, 5],
         [3, 4, 5]],

        [[6, 7, 8],
         [6, 7, 8],
         [6, 7, 8]]])
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer provided by @Alleo. You can use following Einops function.

```
einops.repeat(example_tensor, 'b h w -> (repeat b) h w', repeat=b)
```

Where `b` is the number of times you want your tensor to be repeated and `h`, `w` the additional dimensions to the tensor.

Example -

```
example_tensor.shape -> torch.Size([1, 40, 50]) 
repeated_tensor = einops.repeat(example_tensor, 'b h w -> (repeat b) h w', repeat=8)
repeated_tensor.shape -> torch.Size([8, 40, 50])
```

More examples here - https://einops.rocks/api/repeat/

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly repeating values can quickly create huge memory cost. In most cases, you can keep the values implicit by utilizing broadcasting instead. So can use `A[:, None, :]` and get as new shape `A.shape==(M, 1, N)`.

One case where I would agree to repeating the values, is that of in-place operations in the following steps.
As numpy and torch differ in their implementations I like the agnostic `(A * torch.ones(K, 1, 1)))` followed by a transpose.